# Backbone js is not loading its Validation Function

Tags: backbone.js

I am working on simple application where i am creating new window in which i am loading Backbone.js which is not loading its Validation function don't know why.
Backbone.Validation function is there on main Window from which i am creating new detached window.[image]

Main window png describes Validation is there.

New Detached window shows that validation is not there.
[image]

Help me with this please.